# Concatenation error sql

Tags: repository, symfony, query-builder

I have a SQL Statement like this :

```
$queryBuilder0 = "
SELECT molecule.molecule, molecule.cas, molecule.statutvlep8h, molecule.statutvlepct,
       molecule.vlep8hMg, molecule.vlepctMg,molecule.unitevlep, IDENTITY(prelevement.laboratoire)
FROM AppBundle:Molecule molecule
INNER JOIN AppBundle:Prelevement prelevement
WHERE prelevement.molecule= molecule.id 
";
```

I want to concat to this statement LIKE in SQL. So I write :

```
$queryBuilder0 = $queryBuilder0.'WHERE molecule.cas  LIKE '%$data->value%' ';
```

But I got symfony error when I try to do :

```
$this->_em->createQuery($queryBuilder0)->getResult();
```

How can I do ?

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used single speech marks for your string and in your extended query. It is all about your use of delimiting your strings.

Simple fix would be to use double speech marks

```
$queryBuilder0 =$queryBuilder0." WHERE molecule.cas LIKE '%$data->value%' ";
```

Or escape you quotes
`$queryBuilder0 =$queryBuilder0.' WHERE molecule.cas LIKE \'%$data->value%\'` ';

Or just append the xtra bit without restating the variable;

```
$queryBuilder0 .= " WHERE molecule.cas LIKE '%$data->value%' ";
```